# How to get proper alignment for font awesome icons with Bootstrap Nav bar links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Live example http://jsbin.com/wupume/1/edit

HTML

```
 <ul class="fa-ul nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
</ul>
```

According to [this font-awesome example page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) we can use icons with unordered list but when I try to use with anchor links `<a href=#">` and `.nav` class too icon placement is not proper.

I want to know if there is any way to have proper alignment without writing custom css.

Comment: Is `nav nav-sidebar` a custom class? I'm not familiar with that being in Bootstrap. Removing `nav nav-sidebar` resolves the issue, as seen here: http://www.bootply.com/5Tqdvv6ipp

Comment: maybe a table structure without borders

Comment: @TimLewis That's the question. nav-sidebar can be removed but .nav is a bootstrap's own class which is conflicting with font-icons

Comment: Ah. I get it now. `fa-ul` and `nav nav-...` seem to be conflicting. Looking into it more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. It seems that `fa-ul` and `nav nav-whatever` do not cooperate. I removed the `fa-ul` from the `<ul>` tag and added in `nav nav-pills nav-stacked` to make a vertical list. Then, I also removed `fa-li` from the `<a>` tags and everything seems to align properly:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> List icons</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the Bootply:

[Bootply - Nav with FA Icons](http://www.bootply.com/7Renf8xGA4)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would have been to use the [fixed width](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width) class `fa-fw` instead of `fa-ul` and `fa-li`.

So the HTML markup would become:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
</ul>
```

Live example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fapidiwulu/edit?html,output)

Answer (score -1):

Remove Nav

`<ul class="fa-ul nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</a></li>
</ul>`